# How to test for spatial correlation in the residuals of a dynamic panel data model?

Tags: r, panel-data, stata, spatial

I have an unbalanced panel on daily data for 8 months for 8 years on a pollutant. Thus, my T is very large and my N(number of cross-section) is 112. My model contains a lagged dependent variable as a regressor or what economists refer to as dynamic panel data model. In addition, I have year and time fixed effects and some other variables.

I wish to test whether my residuals from an OLS regression are spatially correlated where the spatial correlation dies out as the distance between the cross-section units decreases.

I don't know how can I do so in the dynamic panel framework with missing observations and a very large T. So please suggest something.